Generic struct ‘ObservedObject’ requires that …. conform to ‘ObservableObject’
I’m not sure what I am missing but I am trying to make use of an
ObservableObject
to update items in my view after an API call has run, however I keep getting the above error message.
I have a function that calls an API and retrieves a set of data and was previously working for just one call. I’m take this data and add it to a second var ready to combine with data from a second call.
Code:
struct consWrapper: Codable {
    let results: [ConsumptionData]
}

struct ConsumptionData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let consumption: Float
    let interval_start: String
}

var combinedData = [combinedIntervalData]()

func getReadings (completed: @escaping ([combinedIntervalData]) -> ()) {

//…

  let consumptionResults = try JSONDecoder().decode(consWrapper.self, from: data)
    consumptionResults.results.forEach { joinedInterval in 
      let intervalDate = combinedIntervalData(id: joinedInterval.interval_start, consumptionVal: joinedInterval.consumption, exportVal: 0)
      combinedData.append(intervalDate)    
  }
  DispatchQueue.main.async { completed(combinedData)}
}

I then wanted to add a second set of data to the same combinedData, the exportVal previously set to a default which I am doing with:

let exportResults = try JSONDecoder().decode(consWrapper.self, from: data)
  exportResults.results.forEach { joinedInterval in 
    let savedData = combinedData.filter({$0.id == joinedInterval.interval_start})[0]
    savedData.exportVal = joinedInterval.consumption
}  

Everything is working for the first call but the second call, which I am able to print to the console and seethe above code does show each of the right values for the two dates it is using to identify and the old and new values. However, it is not reflected on the screen which I understood be due to originally using a @State so am trying to move to use ObservableObject but still no luck.
class combinedIntervalData: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    @Published var consumptionVal: Float
    @Published var exportVal: Float
    
    init(id: String, consumptionVal: Float, exportVal: Float) {
        self.id = id
        self.consumptionVal = consumptionVal
        self.exportVal = exportVal
    }
}

And in my view am calling this with
@ObservedObject var combinedData:[combinedIntervalData] = []

I’ve tired a few suggestions form other posts but not sure what I am missing. Any help greatly appreciated.
I’ve also added several print() because if I change the view back to @State the code doesn’t show as having any issues but the app just crashes with unknown reason and it seems it gets as far as getting the request for the second call which I can see looks correct. This happens just before the line
let exportResults = try JSONDecoder().decode(consWrapper.self, from: data)

You're not using your ObservableObject directly, but an array... plenty of duplicates: Published works for single object but not for array of objects, How to update state in an ObservableObject array in SwiftUI, Why is an ObservedObject array not updated ...?

Have a look at this Apple link  Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.

HI, thanks for the comments. I had come across some of those links but still not able to replicate in my instance. Taking the last link from @pilchard Why is an ObservedObject array not updated in my SwiftUI application? I’ve tried to replicate everything over but as soon I replace the hardcoded values used in that example with my var combinedData I get nothing pulling through to the view.

You can't use ObservedObject in an array, you need to make it directly equal to an instance of an ObservableObject.
See Apple's ObservedObject documentation. The use of ObservableObject is not needed in this situation and you can simply use an identifiable class.
